# ERROR send and transfer are only available for objects of type address payable , not address

Tags: solidity

```
function finalizeRequest(uint index) public restricted {
    Request storage request = requests[index];
    
    require(request.approvalCount > (approversCount / 2));
    require(!request.complete);
    
    request.recipient.transfer(request.value);
    request.complete = true;
}
```

error line ---> `request.recipient.transfer(request.value);`

can someone help me with this? Thank you.

solidity version I'm using:

```
pragma solidity >0.4.17 <0.8.0;
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to mark the `request.recipient` as `payable`

```
payable(request.recipient).transfer(request.value);
```

---

From the docs page [Solidity v0.8.0 Breaking Changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/080-breaking-changes.html):

> *The global variables `tx.origin` and `msg.sender` have the type `address` instead of `address payable`. One can convert them into `address payable` by using an explicit conversion, i.e., `payable(tx.origin)` or `payable(msg.sender)`.*

Comment: That gives me: ParserError: Expected primary expression.payable(orders[i].investor).transfer(msg.value * orders[i].amount / totalRaised);
            ^-----^

Comment: @lampbottle This seems like a syntax error unrelated to this question. Please [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a separate question with steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: It was because I was using an older version of solidity

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a complier older than 0.6, you can declare `recipient` as `address payable` instead of `address`.
If you are using a compiler more or equal to 0.6, you can use the solution provided by @Petr Hejda.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in code its fine but upon execution i passed address then i get Error as given below in Remix ide

:status false Transaction mined but execution failed"
transact to transferEther.payBill errored: VM error: revert.

revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.