# TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address". Error on compiling contract on remix ide

Tags: compiler-errors, solidity, transfer, compile-time, remix

```
//send funds to user
msg.sender.transfer(etherBalanceOf[msg.sender]); //eth back to user
token.mint(msg.sender, interest); //interest to user

//reset depositer data
depositStart[msg.sender] = 0;
etherBalanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
isDeposited[msg.sender] = false;

emit Withdraw(msg.sender, userBalance, depositTime, interest);
```

- Error is in the line **msg.sender.transfer(etherBalanceOf[msg.sender]);**
- Solidity Version 8.0.0

If someone could please look into this error , thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR send and transfer are only available for objects of type address payable , not address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341914/error-send-and-transfer-are-only-available-for-objects-of-type-address-payable)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late, but you need to cast msg.sender to payable, this will give you access to methods such as transfer and send.

```
payable(msg.sender).transfer(etherBalanceOf[msg.sender])
```

Comment: any idea why it is saying "expected primary expression" when i try to do so? 
 `        payable(msg.sender).transfer(withdrawAmmount);
`