# Sending ether to a payable function in Solidity doesn't decrease the sender's Ether in Ganache

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

I have the following smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./IERC20.sol";
import "./MyCoinSupply.sol";

contract MyCoinDEX
{
    IERC20 public token;

    event Bought(uint256 amount);
    event Sold(uint256 amount);

    constructor() public
    {
        token = new MyCoinSupply();
    }

    function getSenderAddress() public view returns (address) // for debugging purposes
    {
        return (msg.sender);
    }

    function getAddress() public view returns (address)
    {
        return address(this);
    }

    function getTokenAddress() public view returns (address)
    {
        return address(token);
    }

    function buy() payable public // send ether and get tokens in exchange; 1 token == 1 ether
    {
      uint256 amountTobuy = msg.value;
      uint256 dexBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
      require(amountTobuy > 0, "You need to send some ether");
      require(amountTobuy <= dexBalance, "Not enough tokens in the reserve");
      token.transfer(msg.sender, amountTobuy);
      emit Bought(amountTobuy);
    }

    function sell(uint256 amount) public // send tokens to get ether back
    {
      require(amount > 0, "You need to sell at least some tokens");
      uint256 allowance = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
      require(allowance >= amount, "Check the token allowance");
      token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341914/error-send-and-transfer-are-only-available-for-objects-of-type-address-payable
      payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
      emit Sold(amount);
    }

}
```

if I call the `buy()` method from `truffle console`, it executes without any exceptions:

```
truffle(development)> MyCoinDEX.buy({value: 1})
```

I verified that the account calling the `buy()` method receives the token. **However, the balance of Ether in Ganache for the account calling the `buy()` method doesn't decrease.** So essentially, the account is getting tokens for free.

**What's going on here? How do I fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it would be necessary to investigate about the balance of the contract account. The gas for `token.transfer` might be paid by the contract account balance, since the contract account is the transaction sender for token contract.

Or the balance decrement would be unnoticeable because it is too small.

I would be happy to know about the answer if you have found out.