# typeerror send and transfer are only available for objects of type address payable not address

Tags: solidity, remix

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
// import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

contract FundMe {

```
// using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;

mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;

function fund() public payable {
    // min $50
    uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10 ** 18;
    // 1gwei < $50
    require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
    addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    // what the ETH -> USD conversion rate

}

function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) {
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
    return priceFeed.version();
}

function getPrice() public view returns(uint256) {
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
    (, int price,,,
    ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    return uint256(price * 10000000000);

}

// 1000000000
function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
    uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethPrice) / 1000000000000000000;
    return ethAmountInUsd;
}

function withdraw() payable public {
    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

}

==========================================
this is my error

from solidity:
TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address".
--> contracts/FundMe.sol:44:9:
|
44 |         msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
|         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR send and transfer are only available for objects of type address payable , not address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341914/error-send-and-transfer-are-only-available-for-objects-of-type-address-payable)

Comment: In your case `payable(msg.sender).transfer(...)`

Comment: thanks it's working now

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
payable (msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).