# Smart Contract withdraw function does not work and i get an error

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

the withdraw function gets me an error and it shows send and transfer are only available for  object of type address payable and not address...

Confusing!!

solidity

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 

//this line of code was created to fund account 
//show the value of fund in the address

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
// the fundMe contract should be able to accept payment 



    function withdraw()payable public {
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR send and transfer are only available for objects of type address payable , not address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341914/error-send-and-transfer-are-only-available-for-objects-of-type-address-payable)

Comment: In your case `payable(msg.sender).transfer(...)`

Answer (score 2):

In Solidity, there is a difference between a normal address and a payable address so the correct way to send Ether to the sender would be `payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);` this converts the normal address to a payable address. For more details take a look at [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64108/whats-the-difference-between-address-and-address-payable)

Answer (score 0):

I think up until `solidity ^0.8.0`, `msg.sender` was payable. `withdraw` function should be called only by the owner of the contract and you do not need to make it payable.

```
address payable private owner;
// set the owner when the contract is created
constructor(){
   owner=payable(msg.sender)
}

function withdraw() public {
       require(msg.sender==owner,"only contract owner can call this");
       owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
```

However, using `transfer` is not safe. Because `.transfer()` sends more gas than 2300. Thus making it possible for reentrancy. A better way would be:

```
function withdraw() public {
           require(msg.sender==owner,"only contract owner can call this");
           (bool success, ) = owner.call{value:address(this).balance}("");
           // success should be true
           require(success,"Withdraw failed")
        }
```