# How to send ETH to smart contract?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I want an address to send ETH to the smart contract in the RSVP function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract MeetingCreation {

    struct Meeting {
        address meeting_creator;
        uint256 meetingID;
        string name;
        string description;
        uint256 start_date;
        uint256 end_date;
        uint256 max_tickets;
        uint256 ticket_price;
        uint256 current_tickets_sold;
        address[] attendees;
        
    }
   function sendETHtoContract(uint256 j) public payable {
   }

    function RSVP (uint256 MEETINGID) public payable {
        //get the Meeting ID
        Meeting storage m = meetings[MEETINGID];

        require(m.current_tickets_sold < m.max_tickets,
            "No more tickets available"
        );

        require(msg.sender.balance >= m.ticket_price,
            "Not enough funds"
        );

        console.log("funds before paying", msg.sender.balance);
        console.log("funds in smart contract before paying", address(this).balance);

        //Attempt #1 To send ETH to contract
        sendETHtoContract(m.ticket_price);

     
        //Attempt #2 To send ETH to contract
        (bool success, ) = address(this).call{value: m.ticket_price}("");

       
        //Attempt #3 to send ETH to contract
         payable(address(this).transfer(msg.value));

        console.log("funds AFTEr paying", msg.sender.balance);
        console.log("funds in smart contract AFTER paying", address(this).balance);

        address[] storage adr;
        adr = m.attendees;
        adr.push(msg.sender); 
        m.current_tickets_sold += 1;
        
    }
```

Both sendETHtoContract and (bool, success) result in not sending any ETH when I tried 3 different addresses.

```
funds before paying 9999949127225257315696
funds in smart contract before paying 0
funds AFTEr paying 9999949127225257315696
funds in smart contract AFTER paying 0
funds before paying 9999955000801324655336
funds in smart contract before paying 0
funds AFTEr paying 9999955000801324655336
funds in smart contract AFTER paying 0
```

When I tried using the transfer function, this is the error I get when the contract tries to compile:

`"send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address".`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR send and transfer are only available for objects of type address payable , not address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341914/error-send-and-transfer-are-only-available-for-objects-of-type-address-payable)

Comment: I tried using payable(address(this).transfer(msg.value)); but got that same error

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can delete your attempt for the simple reason that when you add `payable` modifier, it handle the transfer about ETH from address to smart contract and viceversa.
Said this, I think that you're not enhancing msg.value field. If you using remix IDE, before call `RSVP` function go into **DEPLOY & RUN TRANSACTIONS** section and put into VALUE textbox a value that you want sending to smart contract and then you can call `RSVP` function.
I adjust your smart contract delete your attempts. Try it:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract MeetingCreation {

    struct Meeting {
        address meeting_creator;
        uint256 meetingID;
        string name;
        string description;
        uint256 start_date;
        uint256 end_date;
        uint256 max_tickets;
        uint256 ticket_price;
        uint256 current_tickets_sold;
        address[] attendees;
    }

    mapping(uint => Meeting) meetings;

    function RSVP (uint256 MEETINGID) public payable {
        //get the Meeting ID
        Meeting storage m = meetings[MEETINGID];

        require(m.current_tickets_sold < m.max_tickets,
            "No more tickets available"
        );

        require(msg.sender.balance >= m.ticket_price,
            "Not enough funds"
        );

        address[] storage adr;
        adr = m.attendees;
        adr.push(msg.sender); 
        m.current_tickets_sold += 1;
    }

    // NOTE: Get smart contract balance
    function getSmartContractBalance() external view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```